# How to discover the index type of an Oracle 12c associative array from the dictionary views?

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle 12c, I have the following PL/SQL package

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE x AS
  TYPE t IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  FUNCTION f RETURN t;
END x;
/
```

I would now like to dynamically discover the return type of the above function `f`:

```
SELECT *
FROM all_arguments
WHERE package_name = 'X';
```

This query yields something along the lines of

[image]

... which can be parsed into a useful data structure using a fancy recursive query, just in case the table contains records, not numbers (e.g. like [the one in this article for `PL/SQL RECORD`](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/11/08/use-jooq-to-read-write-oracle-plsql-record-types/)).

What I couldn't find in the dictionary views, however, is a formal reference to the index type of the associative array, i.e. `PLS_INTEGER`. Is there any way to discover that in a different view?

Note, I'd like to avoid parsing the contents of `ALL_IDENTIFIERS`, as I cannot rely on `PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL'` on any target systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please forgive me for I have sinned:

```
WITH
  FUNCTION index_type(type_owner VARCHAR2, type_name VARCHAR2, type_subname VARCHAR2) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    l_result VARCHAR2(50) := 'UNKNOWN';
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'[
      DECLARE
        l_result VARCHAR(50);
        v "]' || type_owner || '"."' || type_name || '"."' || type_subname || q'[";
      BEGIN
        BEGIN
          v('A') := NULL;
          l_result := 'VARCHAR2';
        EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
            BEGIN
              v(1) := NULL;
              l_result := 'PLS_INTEGER';
            EXCEPTION
              WHEN OTHERS THEN l_result := 'UNKNOWN';
            END;
        END;

        :result := l_result;
      END;]' USING OUT l_result;

    RETURN l_result;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN RETURN SQLERRM;
  END index_type;
SELECT 
  type_owner, type_name, type_subname,
  index_type(type_owner, type_name, type_subname) AS index_type
FROM all_arguments
WHERE data_type = 'PL/SQL TABLE';
```

Which yields the desired result:

[image]

Of course, the type definition deserves more details, including length, precision, etc, but this is good enough for me.

Comment: I only think it would be a sin if you accessed `X$` views?